# Get query between two datetimes

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code I have:

```
$qry = "SELECT * 
          FROM parties 
         WHERE schoolid = $schoolid AND 
         WHERE timestart BETWEEN '$dateStart 00:00:00' AND '$dateEnd 23:59:59' 
      ORDER BY timestart, attending";
```

This is what I get when I echo the query:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM parties 
   WHERE schoolid = 100 AND 
   WHERE timestart BETWEEN '2013-08-13 00:00:00' AND '2013-09-12 23:59:59' 
ORDER BY timestart, attending
```

It doesn't work. And when I manually run the code in PHPMyAdmin it just tells me I have an error in my syntax. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are typing `WHERE` twice and it has to be only once.

should be like this:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM parties 
   WHERE schoolid = 100 AND 
         timestart BETWEEN '2013-08-13 00:00:00' AND '2013-09-12 23:59:59' 
ORDER BY timestart,attending
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM parties 
   WHERE schoolid = 100 AND 
         timestart BETWEEN '2013-08-13 00:00:00' AND '2013-09-12 23:59:59' 
ORDER BY timestart, attending
```

Remove the **`AND WHERE`**, it's syntactically incorrect - the correct one is a lonely **`AND`** on that spot.

Answer (score 0):

There should be only one WHERE in query unless subquery is used.